# Apache/2.4.38 serving wrong certificate file

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl-certificate

I have an Apache/2.4.25 site serving https for virtualhosts quite happily.

I have a new server using Apache/2.4.38 and a very similar, but smaller, config to the other machine.

When I access a website on the new machine the certificate the browser gets is the default one for localhost, not the one for the virtual domain. (and hence complains about the certificate) but other than that the pages are delivered OK by SSL.

There are no errors reported on starting apache or when the site is accessed.
sudo apachectl configtest says OK

ssl.conf on both machines is the same and has the directives for server localhost certificate enabled. 
The permissions for the domain cert key is root rw only

I can't seem to get any closer than that.

Anyone have any ideas on how to pin down this problem further?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok panic over.
I wasn't aware of the apachectl -S  command (it's not in the man) which would have helped get a view of what was happening.

Turns out I was using the default server name as my virtualhost server name, since really I was taking shortcuts etc.

Once I went through the process of setting a seperate name for the virtual host everything started working as intended.
Thanks